# Document.ready function is not working after new pageload

Tags: jquery, html

My code is like this,

### page1.html

```
<button onclick="loadNextpage();">
<div id="main">
</div>

function loadNextpage()
{
    /*I am calling my back end code here which gives page2.html*/
    $("#main").html(response);
}
```

### page2.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("document.ready in social")
        jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
    });
</script>

<div class"submain">
<time>
     <abbr class="timeago" title=${rec[5]}>${rec[5]}</abbr>
</time>
</div>
```

I am getting page2.html inside specified div. But the problem is two lines inside document.ready function is not working. Please help me in this case.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your page2 is loading via ajax so in this case, in your page2 script should be after that element,it should look like this:

```
<div class"submain">
<time>
     <abbr class="timeago" title=${rec[5]}>${rec[5]}</abbr>
</time>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        alert("document.ready in social")
        jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();

</script>
```

and this line is wrong, which is typing mistake while posting question it looks like:

```
$(#main).html(response);
```

it should be:

```
$("#main").html(response);
```

Comment: This is actually not true.  If you call `$(document).ready()` when the document is already ready, it will just call the callback immediately.

Comment: @jfriend00 if page is loaded via ajax,the code inside will not execute in this case, yes if events are written in ``document.ready()`` they will work

Comment: That is also not true.  `.html()` will execute scripts embedded in the content.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/khqg2gvq/ for a demo.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are not getting my point, i agree it will execute but it is in ``document.ready()``

Comment: `.ready()` will get executed even if the document is already ready.  See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/28Lez0n3/

Comment: agreed @jfriend00 thanks fir corecting me corrected, oreder matters in that case

Answer (score -1):

`$(#main).html(response);`

this line isn't the right way to use jquery
use this:

`$("#main").html(response);`

`<div class"submain">//another bug`

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ about jquery selector